# code optimization in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

Is there any optimization between the following two code snippets?

**case 1:**

```
int func()
{
    int a = 10;
    return a;
}
```

The first case assigns a value to a variable in a function and then returns that variable.

**case 2:**

```
int func()
{
    return 10;
}
```

The second function just returns the value directly.

Also, Which one is faster?

Comment: This is not a very good question. Too broad.....

Comment: First of all, there is no language called C/C++. Second, test it and see.

Comment: the difference is that the first one wont compile

Comment: @tobi303 Maybe in ANSI C, it does not, but that is quite archaic, right?

Comment: @Zereges the typo is fixed in the mean time, not sure what you mean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both functions will result in identical machine code with any half-decent compiler. Optimizing away local temporary variables is something that compilers have been able to do since the 1980s.

This is why using local variables to improve readability of complex expressions is a good idea. In your case the local variable is just superfluous though.

Answer (score 3):

With `-O1` (or higher) switch enabled, both the snippets produce the same assembly,

```
func():
        mov     eax, 10
        ret
```

so, performance-wise, both snippets are same.

Comment: OK, what did I miss? May I ask for an explanation to the DVs?

Comment: I'm curious too. Lack of the explanation of rationale?

Comment: @songyuanyao Not sure, but I'm not sure how it is lacking. Both the snippets produce the same assembly, so there's no difference. What's the reason for DVs? (+3/-3), i'm actually surprised.

Comment: I didn't DV, but I assume it's because answer applies only to specific compiler and architecture, and doesn't assert the fact that on general level this kind of micro-optimization is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Any sensible compiler would be expected to build essentially identical code for these two cases.

Comment: only after fixing the typo in the first version :P

Answer (score 1):

For a simple type like `int` there is almost certainly no difference of any kind in performance. As others point out the Assembler is the same.

For complex types in C++ the answer is much more nuanced and can depend on copy elision and the use of move semantics. That's worth considering particularly when implementing templates which might be instantiated with almost any type.

Good implementations of (say) `std::vector<>` are very careful to not create unnecessary copies that need assigning or moving.

Comment: "an atomic type like int" - the atomic type would be `std::atomic<int>`. There's no guarantee that plain `int` is atomic.

Comment: @MSalters Fair point. That is confusing terminology. I mean built-in primitive types like `int` of course. Edited.